# Oracle Sql: Select only the latest records by an id and a date

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

My table looks like this:

```
ID       FROM     WHEN
1        mario    24.10.19
1        robin    23.10.19
2        mario    24.10.19    
3        robin    23.10.19
3        mario    22.10.19
```

I just want the newest records from an ID. So the result should look like this:

```
ID       FROM     WHEN
1        mario    24.10.19
2        mario    24.10.19    
3        robin    23.10.19
```

I dont know how to get this result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple methods.  For just three columns in Oracle, I have had good luck with `group by`:

```
select id,
       max("from") keep (dense_rank first order by "when" desc) as "from",
       max("when") as when
from t
group by id;
```

Often a correlated subquery performs well, in this case, with an index on `(id, when)`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t."when" = (select max(t2."when") from t t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

And the canonical solution is to use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by "when" desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Oracle has a smart optimizer but this has to do a bit more work, because row numbers are assigned to *all* rows before the filtering.  That can make this a wee bit slower (in some databases) than alternative, but it is still a very viable solution.